# What is the meaning of "recursive" and "full.names" in the list.files function?

Tags: r

I want to understand what `recursive` and `full.names` does in the `list.files()` function.

```
df <- list.files(
  path = "path/to/files",
  recursive = TRUE,
  pattern = "\\.csv$",
  full.names = TRUE
)
```

I already read the R documentation but I still don't fully understand what it does.

I expect someone can help me explain the code with easy to understand example if can.

Comment: It lists the file names in `path` recursively (i.e. including subdirectories), matching pattern fileending `.csv`, where `full.names` prefixes the entire path.

Comment: best way to learn is to have a folder full of files (some of them `.csv`) and just run the code. you can then mess with the parameters just to see what changes

Comment: Thank you. And sorry, next time I will use a more descriptive title.